# research on OR and AND compression in SAT formulas

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability, p-vs-np

this is a new/advanced paper on OR and AND compression of SAT formulas, a newer area of research that seems not covered in any textbooks so far.

> [A simple proof that AND-compression of NP-complete problems is hard](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2014/075/) (Dell)

can follow it generally, but not in detail. so:

> how would this theory be described to undergraduates if possible?

looking for sketches, overview and/or some examples and intuition on this line of research from expert(s) of the kind that might appear in an undergrad textbook. also does it have any implication on P=?NP?

Comment: The cited paper [Infeasibility of Instance Compression and Succinct PCPs for NP∗](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1145/1374376.1374398) seemed (to me) somewhat more comprehensible. It also discusses applications to cryptography; namely, to the creation of collision-resistant hash functions.

Comment: @Patrick thx here is the [link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rsanthan/Papers/NPCompress_proc.pdf) to the paper & note also some further discussion in [TCS chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon), hope others can join in

Comment: You can follow it in general, but not in detail. What in particular is confusing? What should be clarified? What parts of it are "not suitable for undergrads"?