# exponential lower bound on boolean formula conjunctions, what complexity class?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, lower-bounds

This new paper [A Lower Bound for Boolean Satisfiability on Turing Machines](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5970.pdf) by Hsieh asserts an exponential lower bound for a TM time complexity on a problem of finding whether a solution exists to a conjunction of boolean formulas. obviously this problem is not in NP, or it would be a P≠NP proof. But the paper does not give its known complexity class.

> What time complexity class is this problem of finding solutions to conjunctions of boolean formulas in?

Also looking for any other context wrt known theory to place this paper result in, i.e. How does it mesh with other known results etc.

Comment: Why is the problem of deciding if there is a solution to a conjunction of boolean formulas not in NP?

Comment: ok J _touché_ you got me that should read _NP complete_

Comment: Please specify the problem that you want to know the complexity of, in the question, explicitly.  Right now the problem isn't clear to me.  We shouldn't have to read the paper to work out problem you are referring to; the question needs to be self-contained.  Also please define what you mean by "finding solutions to".

Comment: feel the author himself has not clearly delineated the problem (so not totally sure), he seems not to have tied it in to other complexity theory research either (eg via his short/general refs). it seems to be conjunctions of boolean formulas exactly as stated in the question. it seems similar to [other recent research re "SAT compression"](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/25929/research-on-or-and-and-compression-in-sat-formulas). disagree that questions cannot be based on CS papers, seems that dictate would lead to only rather shallow/superficial questions in general.

Comment: vzn, please try to read my comment more carefully.  I didn't say that questions cannot be inspired by or based upon CS papers.  I said that questions need to be self-contained.  Think about it this way: do you want people to answer your question, or not?  If you want people to answer your question, why would you put extra unnecessary barriers in the way of understanding what you are even asking?  Please spend more time figuring out how to frame your question precisely, then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: read your brief comment. understood it. feel if people think they can answer some questions with only their brain/existing knowledge and nothing else, then that will lead to rather shallow/superficial tone on this site. but then again maybe that is kind of the point of se at times? please spend less time criticizing questions and more time figuring out how to answer them, or ignoring them if you dont know the answer :) ... anyway since you seem to feel stinged by the -2, in real spirit of generosity/stackexchange will accept your shallow/superficial/wrong answer if none others materialize :)

Comment: @vzn, if my answer does not answer your question, please don't accept it.  I'm not grubbing for points. I really don't care about rep.  What I *do* care about is maintaining the quality of questions and answers on this site.  Questions that are vague or unclear waste readers' time and do not contribute to our site's mission of building an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others.  Others have expressed similar sentiments to you before; allow me to add my voice as well.

Comment: question/answer "quality" is ***subjective*** and not ***declared*** by anyone in particular. if you feel the question is a "waste of your time" ***dont engage with it***. why are you still defending your cr*p answer? you speak of "our site" but argue/speak in a ***noninclusive*** way. suggest any further remarks in [chat]

Comment: fyi update closer look/review of the paper, it looks like it has a basic error to me, more details on request in chat

Comment: @AliNfr Thanks for editing questions to try to improve them. However, the edits you're making are mostly to closed questions and fixing the grammar and typography of such a question does nothing at all to address the reason why the question was closed in the first place. If we accept the edit, there'll be an automatic reopen vote for the question, which just wastes people's time. It's great that you're trying to help but please focus your efforts on questions that haven't been closed, or edit closed questions in a way that would make them suitable for re-opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your boolean formulas have no quantifiers (just AND, OR, NOT, etc.),
testing validity of a conjunction of boolean formulas is in NP.  It is in fact NP-complete.

Comment: its apparently for formulas that dont share variables in each formula ie are independent. yes the standard/common version of the problem is as you state.

Comment: lol on stackexchange its always the questioners fault isnt it!

Comment: @vzn If omissions in the questioner's question are not the questioner's fault, whose fault are they?

Comment: @DavidRicherby _any omissions are in the eye of the beholder. & anyway so maybe one should just eliminate the highly critical middlemen & answer ones own questions!_